# Export site using stsadm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, stsadm

When I am exporting a SharePoint 2007 site using

```
stsadm -o export -filename c:\sp2007importedbackups\testbackup.cab  -url http://um-pc:6115 -includeusersecurity
```

I am getting the following error:

> Export ran out of memory while compressing a very large file. To successfully export, turn compression off by specifying the -nofilecompression parameter.

Please guide accordingly.

Comment: are you trying to export or import?

Comment: I am doing export.

Comment: Your command says `import` was that a typo?

Comment: Yes.It is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The really big .cmp/.cab files export is creating can't be compressed. One way to workaround this is by specifying the `-cabsize` parameter on the `stsadm -o export` command to "60".

```
stsadm -o export -filename c:\sp2007importedbackups\testbackup.cab -url http://site -cabsize 60 -includeusersecurity
```

[Source](http://garnetsgems.blogspot.com/2010/04/moving-site-export-ran-out-of-memory.html)

Comment: I have tried the -cabsize attribute to 60 but it is still giving me the same error